# SQL count using column of date before and after

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

| ID | type | date | Odertime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2022-03-02 | 2021-06-23 |
| 2 | A | 2022-03-05 | 2021-06-25 |
| 1 | A | 2022-03-02 | 2022-10-09 |
| 3 | A | 2022-03-06 | 2021-04-05 |
| 2 | A | 2022-03-05 | 2022-02-05 |
| 2 | A | 2022-03-05 | 2022-05-13 |

Any idea on how to make this? Thanks.
I want count before and after by columns_date like below:

| ID | type | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Before and after what exactly?

Comment: I want count Odertime before / after cliumn date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not totally clear, but I guess you meant "**date** is after or before **Odertime**", so something like this:

```
select
    id,
    type,
    sum(case when date > odertime then 1 else 0 end) as before,
    sum(case when date < odertime then 1 else 0 end) as after
from test
group by
    id,
    type
```

see [sqlfiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1f68d/3)